# Allow Users to Create their Own Attributes within a templatized Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, csv, time-series

I'm trying to create a data visualization site for time series data.

I want the user to be able to upload their own csv's of time series data.  So that my web application can create graphs from it.

The amount of fields the user can have should be variable. A user can have just `temperature`, or he can have `temperature` and `humidity`.  I want to use only one model to handle the variable amount of fields.  A template model maybe?

I think the problem here is with ActiveRecord and the way I want it. I'd probably have to create a separate Model for each table the user wants to handle different number of fields.

Is there a better way to handle this using ActiveRecord? Suggestions? I'm lost and I haven't been able to move forward at all. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ejay

EDIT:
Another I thought of was a model that represents each data column.  So that every instance would contain the same number attributes. Something like, `:name, :type, :timestamp, :data`.  However, this seems highly inefficient because I would have to access a number of tables in order to upload one csv file.

Is  this the correct way I should be thinking about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggesstion is having only model, called `DataSet`. `DataSet` has three columns, `:name`, `:data` and `:user_id`. The type of `:name` should be something like `varchar(255)`. The type of `:data` is just `text`, and it's purpose is to store a json blob representing the CSV.

Let's say the CSV looks something like this:

```
num,value
1,4
2,5
3,4
4,100
5,60
```

You parse this into a hash that looks like this

```
{
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 100,
  5 => 60
}
```

When you want to write this to the database, just do:

```
DataSet s = DataSet.new
s.name = 'Whatever'
s.data = parse_csv(csv_file).to_json # "{\"1\":4,\"2\":5,\"3\":4,\"4\":100,\"5\":60}"
s.save
```

To get the data back out, you can do this:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode s.data
```

You can ever edit your model to do this conversion automatically:

```
class DataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def data=(data_hash)
    write_attribute :data, data_hash.to_json
  end

  def data
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode read_attribute(:data)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've always heard about json, just never knew how and what it was used for.  I'm a rails newbie, so you're help is greatly appreciated.

For name, do you mean the type of the values like boolean, integer, and float?  In your above example, how would I specify the data type of the individual columns, and then graph it?